# OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument:

Tags: python, json

I'm scraping a lot of reviews from a site with Python, for each review I call the "review" function and then open the file and append it to it. It works for a while but then the following error appears me everytime and not it the same review.

> OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument

I tried json.dumps:

```
scraped_data = reviews(line)
with open('reviews','a' ) as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(scraped_data,f,indent = 4))
```

but the same error keeps appearing. I also tried json.dump:

```
scraped_data = reviews(line)
with open('reviews','a' ) as f:
    json.dump(scraped_data,f,indent = 4))
```

and, for some reason, I tried without indent too.

edit: full traceback for json.dumps:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "s.py", line 202, in <module>
with open('reviews','a' ) as f:
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'reviews'
```

full traceback for json.dump:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "s.py", line 203, in <module>
json.dump(scraped_data,f,indent = 4)
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'reviews'
```

Comment: Would you mind to share the full traceback?

Comment: Yes, I edited the question

Comment: I believe this would require further debugging, as it looks like, the problem is not with writing the dump to file but to dump the scraped data in the first place, try printing the scraped data to find out what's causing the problem.

Comment: What's the exact Linux you are running on? The Errno 22 could have platform dependent meaning. I suggest running `man 2 open`, and reading descriptions for `EINVAL` messages. The best theory I came up with is `O_APPEND` (`'a'`) is somehow badly supported on your system. Try using (`'w'`), this would overwrite file, but if this works then we know the problem is in `'a'`.

Comment: Possibly the OS telling you that you have too many files open? Do you get the same thing if you hard code `scraped_data` to a fixed string?

Comment: Anoter idea just popped into my head: are you using multithreading or multiprocessing or viewing this file form another program? The root of all obscure bugs is concurrency ;)

Comment: Does this really have anything to do with JSON or is this rather a problem opening files? Also, does it have to do anything with scraping at all, or does it just occur in that context? Please extract a [mcve] from your code. Also, as a new user, please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 7):

**On Windows 10**

I noticed the same behavior in my code and I found that I was using Microsoft OneDrive which was causing the same error. The file I was trying to open had its file pointer visible in Windows Explorer but not the contents. Are you using any cloud file sharing service?

(I right clicked the file, selected "Always Keep on this Device", ran the same code again and it worked).

Comment: I was also facing the same issue. I was appending some tweets to a file but was getting "OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument:". When I switched to Ubuntu (which was installed in dual boot mode) and the file was stored locally, the error disappeared.
I tried selecting "Always Keep on this Device" but it doesn't seem to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

try giving it the full path of the file.

make sure you have permission to write in that directory (whatever user the app is running under)

also, if the file does not already exist, it cannot append to it... instead of `a` try `a+`

plus sign means if it is not there then create it

Comment: I tried, and at least on macOS and Debian 'a' works fine for creating new files...

Comment: :shrug: [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) say that '+' is for *reading* and writing, but whatevs...

Comment: You are correct @AndrewMorozko if it is not one of those then they are having an error that is either path or permissions related.

Comment: yep, didn't thing of permissions, although there's `EACCES` for that. Can't we all just agree that errno mechanism is a great solution? Nothing confusing ever happens with it!

Comment: I tried full path and 'a+' and it didn't work :( i'll try the above approach

Comment: how did you build the full path? did you use `os.path.join()`? are you sure you have the correct permissions? make sure it is the user under which the app is running that has the permissions.

Comment: If you are in windows, the ` \\ ` is an escape char and you cannot just use a string' you will need to properly escape it or use a raw string

Comment: the \ not \\ is what I meant - SO made it difficult to rep in the comment

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you open your file as a variable?

```
f = open("reviews", "a")
f.write(json.dumps(scraped_data,f,indent = 4))
f.close()
```

Comment: Can you explain how this will solve the OPs problem? Using a Context Manager to handle opening and closing files is ubiquitous.

Comment: This would not change the call to `open` which produces an error, but would fail to close the file descriptor if something went wrong.